# what is the relationship between the complexity class E(and EXP) and NP?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

I want to know any relationship between the complexity class E(and EXP) and NP.

I also would like to know whether there is any $DTIME$ formulation or relations of $NTIME(O(n^k))$ where n is the size of input, and k is constant.

edit: for example, is NP contained in EXP?

Comment: Yes, NP is contained in EXP.  Have a look at the nice Venn diagram [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-404j-theory-of-computation-fall-2006/).

Comment: @williamdemeo Thank you very much. Can you also help me here: I also would like to know whether $DTIME(O(n^n))$ can represent NP. thank you so much.

Comment: $DTIME(O(n^k))$ can't even represent $P$, let alone $NP$, by the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, he means $O(n^n)$ where $n$ is not constant.

Comment: Well, it is known that $NP \subset EXP$, since you can go over all possible witnesses in time $\tilde{O}(2^{n^k})$.

Answer (score 5):

We have:

$$ P \subseteq NP \subseteq PSPACE \subseteq EXP \,, $$

and $P \subsetneq EXP$. The latter is the result of time-hierarchy theorem; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem#Consequences). Therefore, at least one of the inclusions above is strict, but no one knows which.

Furthermore, we [know](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo%3aE#e) from [Ronald V. Book's 1972](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0201019) paper that $E \ne NP$.